# How to pass address of pointer to thread without it first going out of scope?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multithreading, macos, cocoa

I have an Objective-C method that creates a pointer, then passes it to a new thread using performSelectorInBackground:. The problem is, I need to pass the *address* of the pointer to the thread because I want to free the memory associated with it from within the thread. The problem I'm having is that when the new thread is launched, the calling method ends, causing the pointer to go out of scope. How do I keep it around long enough where the thread can receive the pointer's address?

This all works of course if I simply call the "pointerTest" method on the main thread.

Here's my code:

```
-(void)pointerTest:(NSValue*)pointer
{   
    void **p = (void**)[pointer pointerValue];
    fprintf(stderr,"p was %s\n",(char*)(*p)); //prints "Hello There!"
    free(*p);
    *p = NULL;
}
```

Now, on the main thread:

```
-(IBAction)doTest:(id)sender
{
    char *str = "Hello There!";

    void *p = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
    strcpy(p, str);

    //this works
    //[self pointerTest:[NSValue valueWithPointer:&p]];

    //this fails
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(pointerTest:) withObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:&p]];

    if(!p){
        fprintf(stderr,"p was NULL!\n");
    }else{
        fprintf(stderr,"p was NOT NULL: %s\n",p);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

This code shows that if I don't pass a pointer to pointerTest:, I cannot free p from within pointerTest:

```
-(void)pointerTest:(NSValue*)pointer
{   
    void *p = (void*)[pointer pointerValue];
    fprintf(stderr,"p was %s\n",(char*)p); //prints "Hello There!"
    free(p);
    fprintf(stderr,"p was %s\n",(char*)p); //STILL prints "Hello There!"
    *p = NULL;
    fprintf(stderr,"p was %s\n",(char*)p); //prints "(null)"
}
```

Now, in the calling method:

```
//I pass p, NOT a pointer to p
[self pointerTest:[NSValue valueWithPointer:p]];

if(p){
    //p is not NULL, and in fact I can print its value
    fprintf(stderr,"p was NOT NULL: %s\n",p);
}
```

However, if I pass a pointer to p instead of p, I can free its value as expected from within pointerTest: and upon returning from pointerTest, p is NULL in the calling method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[I won't ask why you're mixing `malloc` a C-strings with Objective-C, I guess you're experimenting. There is nothing wrong with doing so per se, it's just unusual in a situation like this.]*

You don't need to pass a *pointer to a pointer* at all.

A *pointer* is the *name* of a *box*. Some boxes contain characters, some employee records, etc. and some *box names* (of other boxes). `malloc` finds a box of the needed size and returns its name, you can pass that around just like you would pass an integer value - you don't need to pass the name of the box containing the name of the box containing your characters...

Also when you `malloc` you need to allow for the trailing NUL character on a C string, so add 1 to the string length.

Try:

```
- (void) pointerTest:(NSValue *)pointer
{   
   void *p = (void *)[pointer pointerValue];
   fprintf(stderr,"p (%p) was %s\n", p, (char *)p);

   free(p);
}

- (IBAction) doTest:(id)sender
{
   char *str = "Hello There!";

   void *p = malloc(strlen(str)+1); // allow for NUL
   fprintf(stderr,"p is %p\n", p);
   strcpy(p, str);

   // this works
   // [self pointerTest:[NSValue valueWithPointer:p]];

   // and so does this
   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(pointerTest:) withObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:p]];

   if(!p)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"p was NULL!\n");
   }
}
```

Note you don't need to wrap `p` up in an `NSValue` either, nothing wrong with passing a pointer value to an Objective-C method.

HTH

**After Comments**

You are confusing the *validity* of a pointer with what might happen to be in the memory the pointer refers to.

The memory referred to by your pointer *is* freed. Your pointer value is no longer valid after the call to `free` - it is a *dangling pointer*.

The memory referred to by your, now dangling, pointer value may be re-used at any time. It just happens that at the point of your `fprintf` the memory has not yet been re-used and so you see the old contents - freeing memory does not clear it out.

Your store of `NULL` into the variable intends to remove your dangling pointer, doing so might be good practice in general but as you've found out taking the address of a short-lived variable and passing it to another method is a good way to create a dangling pointer. So you ended up trying to clean up a dangling pointer from box A to box B by using a dangling pointer to box A as box A had since been released itself... Let's try that a explaining that a different way ;-)

In this case you created a pointer to the local variable (box) `p` belonging to `doTest`, as soon as `doTest` completes the system returns the box that was being used for `p` to the free-box pile (or stack in this case) and your pointer became a dangling; when your original code for `pointerTest` then tried to store a `NULL` into that box via that, now dangling, pointer you hit a problem.

Comment: Unless I pass a pointer to p to pointerTest:, free() does nothing. In other words, once pointerTest finishes, p is still allocated and points to the same place it did before I passed it to pointerTest. I updated the code to demonstrate this. Oh and thanks for the tip about the null character, I forgot that.

Comment: @Synthetix You don't need to pass a pointer to `p` to `pointerTest:`.  You need to pass a pointer to the block of memory returned by `malloc`.  CRD's code is correct.  If it doesn't do what you need, edit your post to explain your requirements in more detail.

Comment: @Synthetix - I think your confusion is that `free` doesn't change the *value* in `p`, the memory referenced by the value in `p` *is* released. The out-of-date value in `p` is often called a *dangling pointer* and you must be careful not to use such values.

Comment: I updated the question to show what happens when I don't pass a pointer to p to pointerTest:.

Comment: @Synthetix - I've added an addendum to the answer. Just follow the boxes, their contents and their lifetimes... HTH

Comment: @CRD - Thank you. What you've suggested seems to work. However, if I would also like to set the calling function's pointer to NULL in addition to freeing its memory, wouldn't I need to use the double pointer? As you say, a local pointer is created without using **, so setting that to NULL only sets the function/method's local pointer to NULL, not the calling function's. Is that right?

Comment: @Synthetix - You simply cannot easily do what you want. You could impose a requirement on your caller that it must pass a box whose lifetime outlives the caller, but testing such a requirement is hard and as you've found out not enforcing just a requirement leads to errors. Furthermore if you manage to null-out one of the boxes containing a reference to a box you've just freed what about any other boxes which may also reference the now freed box? If you wish to avoid dangling pointers in Objective-C you should consider ARC or GC memory management, avoiding them in plain C requires discipline.

Comment: @CRD Thanks for all your help! You're right, I need to rethink this. I may just end up making the pointer an instance variable. At least that way it will be guaranteed to be accessible by both doTest: and pointerTest:, despite the two running in different threads.